# sed editing specific column and row in a csv file

Tags: bash, csv, sed

I am working on a project that requires me to edit a specific column and row of a csv file.  I have been successful at finding the correct row, getting the row number and even updating the specific column as standard output but not in the .csv file.  The problem I have is putting it all together and getting sed to update the values in the file.

Here is an example of the values in the csv:

```
9847,3132,132,0,168,0,410,73,4400,DC,4300,6,248,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,No,No,No,No,No,LSI,Service,Yes,No,No,pw,Yes,SA
9848,132,3132,0,168,0,410,73,4400,DC,4300,6,248,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,No,No,No,No,No,LSI,Service,Yes,No,No,pw,Yes,SA
9849,3132,132,0,168,0,410,73,4400,DC,4300,6,248,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,No,No,No,No,No,LSI,Service,Yes,No,Yes,pw,Yes,SA
9850,3132,132,0,168,0,410,73,4400,DC,4300,6,248,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,No,No,No,No,No,LSI,Service,Yes,No,Yes,pw,Yes,SA
9851,3132,132,0,168,0,410,73,4400,DC,4300,6,248,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,No,No,No,No,No,LSI,Service,Yes,No,Yes,pw,Yes,SA
9852,3132,132,0,168,0,410,73,4400,DC,4300,6,248,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,No,No,No,No,No,LSI,Service,Yes,No,Yes,pw,Yes,SA
9853,3132,132,0,168,0,410,73,4400,DC,4300,6,248,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,No,No,No,No,No,LSI,Service,Yes,No,Yes,pw,Yes,SA
9854,3132,132,0,168,0,410,73,4400,DC,4300,6,248,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,No,No,No,No,No,LSI,Service,Yes,No,Yes,pw,Yes,SA
9855,3132,132,0,168,0,410,73,4400,DC,4300,6,248,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,No,No,No,No,No,LSI,Service,Yes,No,Yes,pw,Yes,SA
9856,3132,132,0,168,0,410,73,4400,DC,4300,6,248,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,No,No,No,No,No,LSI,Service,Yes,No,No,pw,Yes,SA
9857,3132,132,0,168,0,410,73,4400,DC,4300,6,248,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,Yes,No,No,No,No,No,LSI,Service,Yes,No,Yes,pw,Yes,SA
```

In this example I want to modify the 28th column for item number 9856 to Yes.  My successful commands so far include:

This command gives me a correct return for how I want the line to appear.

```
grep 9856 ./file.csv | awk -F, '$28="Yes"'
```

From here I assume I need to pipe the results to a sed command that will replace the existing line with the updated line but all of my attempts have been unsuccessful!

Also if you could please elaborate on your answers for my learning purposes.  I will also be editing many other column values in this project.

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $1=="9856" {$28="Yes"}1' file`?

Comment: Cyrus, will this command update the existing file.csv?

Comment: This does not update the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed '/^9856,/s/[^,]*/Yes/28' file.csv
```

**Explanations**

- `/^9856,/`: if line starts with `^9856,`
- `s/[^,]*/Yes/28`: replace 28th occurrence of string containing zero or more(`*`) non-comma character(`[^,]*` with `Yes`

To edit the file in place, add the `-i` flag:

```
sed -i '/^9856,/s/[^,]*/Yes/28' file.csv
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!  Would you mind briefly describing the syntax of the command.  It doesn't look too complicated but I would like to learn from it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a complete awk solution

```
awk -F, '$1 == "9856" { for (i=1;i<=25,i++) { printf "%s,",$i } printf "%s,","Yes";for (i=27;i<=NF-1;i++) { printf "%s,",$i } printf "%s",$NF }' filename
```

Check that the first , delimited field equals 9856, then print the first 25 comma separated fields followed by , then "Yes" followed by fields 27 up to the last field but one. We then finally print the last field with no comma at the end.

Comment: Will this awk command update the original file.csv file?  It appears to be editing the string but not updating the file.

Comment: You will need to redirect the output to another file.