# How to remove all non-numeric characters from the value of nth column of a pipe delimited files in UNIX

Tags: regex, file, unix, pipe, delimited

I have file in UNIX with many records having pipe delimiter. I want to remove non alpha numeric and non special character from  the value of  column number 20 which contains phone number and will do right trim 10 digit.

Comment: Please, show us the code of what you tried. Give an short sample of input and the expected output corresponding to that input, and we will help you.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/45444988/2191572. If you need a comprehensive regex for CSV then see https://stackoverflow.com/q/18144431/2191572. You've shown zero attempt so it is impossible to guess how close you are to achieving your goal. Good luck!

Comment: for example the content of a pipe delimited file as below
ABCD|123|HI|123ABCD#$1234|JAY
GEFR|245|BY|2472462342#$41|JAM
her you can see the 4th column having alphanumeric and special  character ,I want to keep only the numeric value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F\| '{ OFS="|";gsub(/[[:alpha:]]|[[:punct:]]/,"",$4);$0=substr($4,(length($4)-10),length($4)) }1' file
```

Set the file delimiter to | and then use gsub to substitute any alpha character or punctuation to empty characters. Print lines.

Comment: how to keep only 10 digit from the right for that 4th column.I mean how to use substr here to achieve that.

Comment: $0=substr($0,(length($0)-10),length($0))

Comment: could you please share the full command adjusting in
 awk -F\| '{ OFS="|";gsub(/[[:alpha:]]|[[:punct:]]/,"",$4) }1' file

Comment: I've amended the answer