# Update csv data in bash

Tags: bash, csv

I am trying to create a bash script that Looks through the csv file and depending on some input that would be the first value in a row of the file, it would increase the value of the second value in the row by 10.

eg. I have the file:

```
Jim,0,
Henry,12,
Louise,6
```

And with the input "Henry", I want to change the 12 to a 24 such that the file saves the value.

I have tried using sed with this

```
while read type time amount
do
        i=$(($i+1))
        if [ $i -eq 2 ];
        then
                x=$time
        fi
done < $INPUT
sed -i '/^Henry,/s/[^,]*/$(($x+10))/1' test.csv
```

so that it searches through the csv until it gets to the second row (array indexing seems to start from 1 in my tests) then it saves the time (the second value in the row) to a variable then I use sid as I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45444988/sed-editing-specific-column-and-row-in-a-csv-file), but it doesn't seem to work, whether it is not saving or not editing I don't know.

I tried to do it with awk, but I don't understand it enough, so if any of you would be kind enough to enlighten me I would be very grateful.

Edit: Fixed bad formatting

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `awk -F ',' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} $1=="Henry"{print $1, $2 * 2; next}1' file`. Btw, make the csv file valid by either removing the last commas or adding one in the last line.

Comment: Thanks, that command prints all the data but doesn't seem to modify it.

Comment: In-place changes are not a very popular concept in console/shells, might even be dangerous because they overwrite without asking. Simply pipe the result to a tmp file and move this to your source, if the result looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

awk doesn't support a "in place" replacement. You should use gawk instead. For example:

```
gawk -F ',' -i inplace '{ $2 = ($1 == "Henry") ? $2+10 : $2 } 1' file.csv
```

-F defines delimeter

{ $2 = ($1 == "Henry") ? $2+10 : $2 }

ternary operator

condition expression ? statement1 : statement2

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/awk/awk_ternary_operators.htm

if condition ? then first : else second
so, if our condition is met, we are adding 10, if not, we just rewrite $2nd field as it was before

and here is a meaning of a 1 at the end:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63891/what-is-the-meaning-of-1-at-the-end-of-an-awk-script

Comment: I have added that, but it doesn't seem to change the values when I read them afterwards, although it seems like it should work, maybe it isn't saving it for some reason?

Comment: My bad, I forgot to add "=" after first $2. Instead of { $2 ($1 == "Henry") ? $2+10 : $2 } it should be { $2 = ($1 == "Henry") ? $2+10 : $2 }. Corrected!

Comment: "Should" is a bit of an overstatement. Regular Awk is fine for most things, but it doesn't have the `-i inplace` option.

Comment: I tried using the updated code, but it is removing all the commas, do you know any to resolve this?

Comment: Solution for this is on stackoverflow also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252745/how-to-keep-the-field-separator-when-printing-0-with-awk

Comment: Thanks that worked for the commas, but something about the command is adding 10 to the number, maybe it is the data type or something, so currently it is going through the file and changing all the values to what they were originally as far as I'm aware, and I don't know why.

Comment: I checked it on my PC a while ago - it works exactly as expected.

Comment: When I run this `gawk -F ',' -i inplace '{ $2 = ($1 == "Henry") ? $2+10 : $2 } 1' OFS=, file.csv` and when my friends run it we all get this as an output:
`
Jim,0
Henry,12
Louise,6
ਬ
`
Are you doing anything different?

Comment: Ok so something about my csv editor was corrupting the file, now it works, thank you so much!